# Set WordPress Transient Expiration via Variable Value

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, transient

I want to set WordPress Transient via Variable Value.

This is an example code with what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<?php 
    if ( false === get_transient( 'special_query_results' ) ) {
        
        $ExpiryInterval = "24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS"; // <--- Storing in Variable

        $RandPostQuery = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>array('tip'),'posts_per_page' => 1,'orderby'=>'rand'));

        set_transient( 'special_query_results', $RandPostQuery , $ExpiryInterval ); // <-- Retriving from Variable
    }
?>
```

I don't know why it's not working. If I try setting directly without variable it's working perfectly. Not sure why it's not working this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$ExpiryInterval = "24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS";
```

`$ExpiryInterval` is being assigned a string, but you need a number.

Consider this example:

```php
$foo = 5 * 10;
$bar = "5 * 10";
```

The value of `$foo` is `50`. The value of `$bar` is `"5 * 10"`. `set_transient` expects a number, not a string, `"24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS"` is text/string, `24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS` is a number. `HOUR_IN_SECONDS` is a  constant equal to the number of seconds in an hour.

Comment: Hey Tom, Thanks for making it clear to understand. I got it working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`HOUR_IN_SECONDS` is a [WordPress constant](https://codex.wordpress.org/Easier_Expression_of_Time_Constants) - you cannot put a constant inside a variable and expect PHP to know it's a constant and not a string when it is parsed. In your example code, I'd just simplify it:

```
set_transient( 'special_query_results', $RandPostQuery , 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
```